# Sending POST request to write in .txt file, response is 201 CREATED but file remains unmodified

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, http-post

I have a problem while trying to write a String in .txt file (located in resources) by sending a POST request (Maven Project).

I have a class called **UserResource.java** in which I wrote a method triggered by request such as: `http://localhost:8080/WebProjekat/users/register`, `/users` is @Path annotation on class level.

```
@Path("/register")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response registerUser(User user) {
    String username;
    if(userService.addUser(user)!=null) {
        username = user.getUsername();
        return Response.status(Status.CREATED)
                       .entity(user)
                       .build();
    } else
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
                       .entity(user)
                       .build();
}
```

In this method there is a call to another method `userService.addUser(user)` which parses a user object into a String and writes it into a file.

```
public User write(User user) {
    System.out.println(user);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfr = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String commentIds = "";
    String themeIds = "";
    String sectionIds = "";
        
    for(int i=0; i < user.getComments().size();i++) {
        if(i != user.getComments().size()-1)
            commentIds+=user.getComments().get(i)+",";
        else
            commentIds+=user.getComments().get(i);
    }
        
    for(int i=0; i < user.getSavedThemes().size();i++) {
        if(i != user.getSavedThemes().size()-1)
            themeIds+=user.getSavedThemes().get(i)+",";
        else
            themeIds+=user.getSavedThemes().get(i);
    }
        
    for(int i=0; i < user.getListOfSections().size();i++) {
        if(i != user.getListOfSections().size()-1)
            sectionIds+=user.getListOfSections().get(i)+",";
        else
            sectionIds+=user.getListOfSections().get(i);
    }
            
    result.append(user.getUsername())
          .append("|")
          .append(user.getPassword())
          .append("|")
          .append(user.getFirstName())
          .append("|")
          .append(user.getLastName())
          .append("|")
          .append(user.getPhoneNumber())
          .append("|")
          .append(sdfr.format(user.getRegistrationDate()))
          .append("|")
          .append(commentIds)
          .append("|")
          .append(themeIds)
          .append("|")
          .append(sectionIds);
       
    try {
        System.out.println(result);
        FileWriter outputFileReader = new FileWriter(userFile,true);
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(outputFileReader);
        outputStream.println(result);
        
        outputStream.close();
            
        return user;
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
        
    return null;
}
```

This is the JSON object that I wrote in Request Body in Postman:

```
{
    "comments": [
        "16",
        "18",
        "222"
    ],
    "firstName": "Milos",
    "lastName": "Ribar",
    "listOfSections": [
        "Section6"
    ],
    "password": "riki995",
    "phoneNumber": "0651941929",
    "registrationDate": "2017-08-10T00:00:00",
    "savedThemes": [],
    "username": "Riki"
}
```

NOTE: I also added a key-value pair : `Content-Type - application/json` in Header section of Postman.

After I send this request, JERSEY successfully finds the class and the method it needs to call, it makes contact with the Server and the Server sends me a response with `Status code : 201 Created` and like I asked a JSON object in a Response Body.
Despite all of that the changes are not made in the file which is located:

```
-WebProjekat
    -src
       -main
          -resources
             -files
                -users.txt
```

I printed out the String right before I tried to write it into a file to check if it reaches the `outStream.println(result)` line and it does.

Comment: Where is userFile set?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that, in the UserService.class constructor

Comment: Show us the value of `userFile`; otherwise, we cannot see where you're trying to write.